# Why does AWS Amplify mangle my static site?

Tags: jekyll, aws-amplify

First, let me say that I'm not a webpage designer.  Far from it. I'm an embedded engineer. 8-) But, I've been using Jekyll to try and create a static webpage. In addition, I'm using AWS Amplify to deploy the webpage. I think that I have the process down. But, my page gets mangled when going from `jekyll serve` to Amplify.

I started from using the Jekyll clean theme https://github.com/scotte/jekyll-clean. Works great when I look at it from `jekyll serve`. Yet, when I look at it from my Amplify URL, https://master.d3e4src368zkzo.amplifyapp.com/ it looks really bad..

I could really use some insight into where to look for why this problem happens.. Seems like something easy but this is all so new to me..

Comment: The styleshets are not being loaded, you can see it on the browser's console "The stylesheet https://master.d3e4src368zkzo.amplifyapp.com/index.html was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”." For some reason, it is trying to load index.html as a css and then fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you resources urls contains `jekyll-clean`.
I guess it comes from your baseurl that might be set to `jekyll-clean`.

In your **_config.yml**, you must read :

```
url: "https://master.d3e4src368zkzo.amplifyapp.com"
baseurl: ""
```

Comment: That's the clue that I needed.. That did help. Like I've previously said, this is all so new to me and the insight was helpful.